# How to excute statement each time a for loop increase to a certain index in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Question, count is incrementing, how do I execute a statement each time count adds +2 or +5 ?

Assuming I'm working with a large list of about 1000 or more entries and I want to execute a different statement each time count gets +10, how do I do that?

```
count = 0
for x in range(10):
    count += 1
    if count == 2:
        print(f'count is now {count}')
```

Comment: Do you mean every multiple of 10?

Comment: You can use [remainder division `%`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to see if a number is a multiple of another. Ex `if count % 10 == 0: print("it is a multiple of 10")`

Comment: Side note: the `count` and `x` variables are redundant. You can just use `for count in range(1, 11):`

Comment: its addition, for each count is +1

Comment: What do you mean by "how do i excute a statment each time count adds +2 or +5."

Comment: the for loop will do stuff 10 times, and count will also increase, now i want to excute a statement, like do hello, when ever count increase by a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is a version of the famous FizzBuzz algorithm:

```
 def fizzbuzz(n):
     for count in range (n):
         if x % 10 == 0:
             print("fizzbuzz")
         elif x % 2 ==0:
             print("fizz")
         elif x % 5 == 0:
             print ("buzz")
         else:
             print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for count in range(1000):
    count += 1
    if count %10 == 0: #if count is multiple of 10, say hello
        print(f'Hello')
    else: #else count normally
        print(f'count is now {count}')
```

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is what i need but what if the list has more than 1000 entries and i want to print hello each time count add 10. like for every +10

Comment: there you go. I edited the answer.